# Non-Deterministic Rep Increase for Deleting Posts

Tags: support, reputation

I am going through my old answers (from when I was new to SO and didn't know better) to delete the ones that make no sense.

In doing so, I discovered that I my reputation increases if I delete my old posts. However, I discovered further that the second and third posts that I deleted earned me +6 rep, while the first one earned me +8 rep:

[image: Non-deterministic ++rep when sequentially deleting own posts]

I'm not particularly concerned about the +2 rep difference between the two; I'm just trying to understand why they were different. Can anyone clarify why this may be the case?

Comment: The first two had 3 downvotes each, for -6 score. The second one had 4 downvotes, which gave you -8. When you removed them, you got rep back accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the posts had downvotes, you lost 2 rep with each vote and get it back when you delete the post. Since you've recently been awarded Peer Pressure I know you've deleted at least one post with 3 or more downvotes. 3 downvotes, no upvotes would cost you 6 rep which you would get back on deleting the post. For 8 returned rep, I guess you had 4 downvotes and no upvotes.

Good call deleting those ones I'd say :-)

Comment: Your guess is correct

Comment: in theory, the post could have 1 upvote and 8 downvotes, or 2 upvotes and 13 downvotes, etc

Comment: Yes, but I can see the posts.

Answer (score 5):

You'll only gain reputation when one of your posts is deleted if it was down-voted (and down-voted significantly *more* than it was up-voted).

See: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)